# How to inject JavaScript into a website through the URL bar?

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

Here is the JavaScript code I inject into the page:

```js
javascript:{document.head.innerHTML+='<script>function inject(){alert("hello");}</script>';
document.body.innerHTML+='<button onclick="inject()">Run</button>';}
```

After running this code in the URL bar, I inspect the source code of the website. Both the button and the function definition are present, however pressing the button does not run the alert as one would expect.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Because the syntax is completely wrong

Comment: Probably the site does proper output filtering to prevent XSS attacks.

Comment: Why would adding some text to the `<head>` define a function? What button? Are you really inspecting the source code (because it sounds like you are inspecting the live DOM)?

Comment: You need to inject your JS code into a <script> tag, and you also need to set the button's `onclick` prop to "inject()" to bind it. currently you just add your function as clear text.

Comment: If you want to execute js directly in the browser, the best way is to use the element inspector's web console, which is a built in at least in firefox and chrome...

Comment: @thefourtheye scripts added via the address bar cannot be filtered by the site; they just run. XSS attacks are all about getting javascript to run *without* the user's involvement (and yes there are several ways to prevent that). Anyway mplungjan is correct; it fails because the syntax is totally wrong.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. some browsers no longer accept javascript: directly from the location bar, they need you to call the script from a bookmarklet
2. your syntax smells of wishful thinking. What you try here would never work that way

This syntax:

```
javascript:(function() { var s = document.createElement("script"); s.src="somejsurl.js";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(s)})()
```

might be a better start

To get this to execute, you would need to create an html page with

```
<a href="javascript:(function() { var s = document.createElement('script'); s.src='somejsurl.js';document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(s)})()">Exec</a>
```

using single quotes inside the href code and load and drag the "Exec" to the bookmarks

While testing, Chrome and Firefox has a command line you can use

If you want to create the script and not load it, you would need to inline the script in the button you created:

```
javascript:(function() { var b = document.createElement("button"); b.onclick=function() { alert('hello')}; b.innerTHML='Hello';})()
```

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers have decided to limit javascript use in the URL bar for security purposes...

Comment: Not the only reason here. His script would never work