# Button element is not retrieved at the first call

Tags: javascript, button, getelementbyid

I've came across a curious thing while scripting in JavaScript and I'm not entirely sure if my way of understanding it is correct.
Basically I would like to click a button which brings up another one, if the second button is not brought up by the first I need to quit the loop.

```
var intervalID = window.setInterval(myfunc,1000);

function t(){
    console.log('quit');
    clearInterval(intervalID);
}

function myfunc(){
    //first button
    document.getElementsByClassName('hit')[0].click();
    //try to retrieve the second one
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('hit_ok');
    console.log(el.length);
    //if it exists click it
    if (el.length == 1){
        el[0].click();
    //otherwise exit
    } else {
        console.log('ready to quit');
        window.setTimeout(t,50);
    }
}
```

My problem is that the first instance returns always 0 in the if statements
I also tried the following:

```
function myfunc(){
    document.getElementsByClassName('hit')[0].click();
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName('hit_ok');
    console.log(el);
    if (el != null){
        el[0].click();
    } else {
        console.log('ready to quit');
        window.setTimeout(t,50);
    }
}
```

and in fact it returns:

[] --> length: 0__proto__: HTMLCollection

VM3642:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined

instead of:

[span.hit_ok]

Which means that the first time it cant retrieve the button.
Clearly the second button is there since the first one is pressed.

HTML code:

```
//first button
<div class="try">
    <input type="hidden" id="isHit" value="">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="hit">Try</a>
</div>

//second button
<div class="msgbox_button">
    <span class="hit_ok" onclick="remove();">OK</span>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Regards,

Comment: a curious thing is that it doesn't even enter in the else loop. I know i am missing something.

Comment: Your HTML? Looks like youve messed sth up there...

Comment: Can you please add an working example that illustrates your problem.

Comment: Where do you call myfunc? It has to be called after load

Comment: added what you've asked, can't add more since HTML code is not mine

Comment: Instead of clicking "hit_ok" simply do remove() ...!?

Comment: remove() is not defined by me, i would rather keep a click on the button and let the site do what it is used to do with a real user click. Anyway that's not the issue here

Comment: The real question is why at the first var el = document.getElementsByClassName('hit_ok'); the set is empty

Comment: Try to click on element "try" 0

Comment: I didnt get it sorry, what do you mean?

Comment: Small tip: add @jonas w to your code to notice me... However, you try to click onto "hit" but its just a div. Try clicking on "try" as it starts the js...

Comment: @Jonasw my bad the script is already as you stated i copy/pasted wrongly, i corrected it in the question. Problem is still there.

Comment: You add it into the urlbar right? You know that you need different syntax there...

Comment: @Jonasw what do you mean with different? i generally add javascript: at the beginning

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19078810/i-inject-javascript-into-a-website-through-the-url-bar-but-it-doesnt-run may you should read this...

Comment: @Jonasw i dont understand your answer, the script is running correctly except for the first cycle. Are you answering for trial and error perhaps?

Comment: Well i try to help you, but i really cant find the problem...

Comment: @Jonasw i read somewhere that a full loaded page doesnt mean a fully loaded DOM lists. Perhaps it's that.. the elements is not fully loaded? i just dont know since the page is loaded for more than 1 minute

Comment: @user217354: the window onload is fired after it ...

Answer (score 0):

What you do:

```
intervalID=window.setInterval();
```

This is valid js, but the script is started  *before* the page has loaded, wich means the DOM is not created at that time.

What to do:

```
window.onload=function(){
var intervalID=window.Interval(...);
};
```

This starts the loop after the page has loaded

Comment: code is inserted in the url bar hence the page is already fully loaded.